# Set radio based on another radio

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have this form:

```
<form name="test">
<input type="radio" required="required" name="a" value="1">1
<input type="radio" required="required" name="a" value="X">X
<input type="radio" required="required" name="a" value="2">2
<br />
<input type="radio" required="required" name="b" value="1">1
<input type="radio" required="required" name="b" value="2">2
</form>
```

I want to achieve this:

```
If a=1 then b=1
If a=X then unset b
If a=2 then b=2
```

I tried this, but it doesn't do anything:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').on('change', function() {
        if ($("input[name='a']:checked").val()=="1") {
        $( "#b" ).prop( "checked", true );
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

What's missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind change event on `radio` button with name `a`, get its value, find the same in `radio button` with name `b` set, and check its property, as below:

```js
$('input[name="a"]').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $('input[name="a"]:checked').val();
  if (selected == "X") {
    $('input[name="b"]:checked').prop("checked", false);
    return false;
  }
  $('input[name="b"][value="' + selected + '"]').prop("checked", true);

});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="test">
  <input type="radio" required="required" name="a" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" required="required" name="a" value="X">X
  <input type="radio" required="required" name="a" value="2">2
  <br />
  <input type="radio" required="required" name="b" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" required="required" name="b" value="2">2
</form>
```

> **PS:** If you wish you can add `disabled` property to `radio button` set with name `b` so that user is not allowed to change them

Answer (score 2):

You should bind the `change` event to the radiobutton, not to the form.
Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<form name="test">
  <input type="radio" required="required" name="a" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" required="required" name="a" value="X">X
  <input type="radio" required="required" name="a" value="2">2
  <br />
  <input type="radio" required="required" name="b" value="1">1
  <input type="radio" required="required" name="b" value="2">2
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='a']").on("change", function() {
    $("input[name='b']").prop("checked", false);
    $("input[name='b'][value='" + $(this).val() + "']").prop("checked", true);
  });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/s6aj043g/)